# How to Use DataFrame Created in Scala in Databricks' PySpark

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, databricks

My Databricks notebook is on Python.
Some codes in the notebook are written in Scala (using the %scala) and one of them is for creating dataframe.

If I use Python/PySpark (the default mode) again, how can I use / access this dataframe that was created when it was on scala mode?

Is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access DataFrames created in one language with another language through temp tables in SparkSQL.

For instance,  say you have a DataFarame in scala called `scalaDF`.  You can create a temporary view of that and make it accessible to a Python cell, for instance:

```scala
scalaDF.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")
```

Then in a Python cell you can run

```py
pythonDF = spark.sql("select * from my_table")

pythonDF.show()
```

The same works for passing dataframes between those languages and R.  The common construct is a SparkSQL table.